# equivalent way using apply family instead of a for loop to get max value of each row in list of sublists R

Tags: r, apply, do.call

What would be the equivalent to this using `apply` family functions or a compbination between `do.call` and `apply`? I would like to keep it simple and when possible in one line:

```
a <- list(  as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12),4,3)),
            as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12),4,3)),
            as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12),4,3))
         )

l <- list()
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  l[[i]] <- apply(a[[i]],1,max)
}

b <- do.call(data.frame, l)
```

Comment: @SimonO101 I'm sorry if am disapointing anyone. I though that by accepting the answer was providing credit to the author. I'm happy to cast more upvotes it that's the way it works. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sapply` for this particular example, however I don't know how representative this example is of your actual larger problem.

```
> sapply(a, function(x) apply(x, 1, max))
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.5757814 0.9189774  0.6198257
[2,] 0.1836433 0.9438362  0.4179416
[3,] 1.5117812 1.1249309  1.3586796
[4,] 1.5952808 0.5939013 -0.1027877
```

`sapply` will simplify to a matrix whenever possible. If you want a `data.frame`, just wrap the output in `data.frame`.

Comment: like this it seems easier... many thanks! is there any reason why you prefer `sapply` to `lapply`?

Comment: @eccehomo, `lapply` will create a `list`, `sapply` will simplify to a `matrix`, as I mentioned. So, for this particular problem, it seemed more appropriate.

Comment: vapply is even better, especially if you're writing a function.

Comment: @hadley, I've heard good things about `vapply`, but it doesn't often come to mind--in part because of a very meager serving of help-page documentation. In this case, do you say it's better because we can specify what form the output should take?